# Error with Severless Function using Lambda AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless

I followed the below link to do a similar setup with S3 static website + AWS API Gateway + AWS Lambda.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/create-dynamic-contact-forms-for-s3-static-websites-using-aws-lambda-amazon-api-gateway-and-amazon-ses/

I am getting 405 Method not allowed when I hit the submit button on the s3 form. I know S3 static web hosting doesn't allow POST. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Why wouldn't static S3 web hosting allow POST? You can definitely run client side JS which would use POST to call your API gateway. You need to add a bit more info to this question

Comment: lamba funtcion works perfectly in test run inside the aws, but I'm not able evoke the api from outside ps postman works good

Comment: Postman hitting API works good? That seems like it should be fine then. As long as your API has CORS enabled and your authentication is setup properly then you're fine

Comment: why not using S3 rest api endpoint ? It supports POST with FormData